# EF 4.1 byte[] not being loaded from the DbContext

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 entities.

```
public class Foo
{
   public virtual int FooId {get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public virtual int BarId { get; set;}
   public virtual byte[] Value { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

When I load Foo from the database by FooId, it is completely hydrated, when I navigate to Bar, it has the correct BarId and Date from the database, but Value is always a byte[0].

Why?

The database is a varbinary(300) column.

The value in the database if I do `select * from Bar` in Management Studio shows

```
BarId      Value            Date
 1      0x20CF30467ABD   10/19/2011
```

Thoughts?

My mapping:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
       ToTable("Foo");

       HasKey(m => m.FooId);
       Property(m => m.Date);

        HasMany(m => m.Bars)
                .WithMany(l => l.Foos)
                .Map(m =>
                         {
                             m.ToTable("FooBars");
                             m.MapLeftKey("FooId");
                             m.MapRightKey("BarId");
                         });
    }
}
public class BarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarConfiguration()
    {
       ToTable("Bar");

       HasKey(m => m.BarId);
       Property(m => m.Value);
       Property(m => m.Date);

        HasMany(m => m.Foos)
                .WithMany(l => l.Bars)
                .Map(m =>
                         {
                             m.ToTable("FooBars");
                             m.MapLeftKey("BarId");
                             m.MapRightKey("FooId");
                         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit but I can't see your problem.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    #region Public Properties

    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual int FooId { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Bar
{
    #region Public Properties

    public virtual int BarId { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] Value { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(m => m.FooId);

        HasMany(m => m.Bars)
                .WithMany(l => l.Foos)
                .Map(m =>
                    { 
                        m.ToTable("FooBars");
                        m.MapLeftKey(f => f.FooId, "FooId");
                        m.MapRightKey(b => b.BarId, "BarId");
                    });
    }
}
public class BarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(m => m.BarId);
    }
}
```

When I do this I get the byte[] back from the database

```
using(var context = new FooBarContext())
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.Date = DateTime.Now;

            var bar = new Bar();
            bar.Date = DateTime.Now;
            bar.Value = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string");

            foo.Bars.Add(bar);

            context.Foos.Add(foo);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using(var context = new FooBarContext())
        {
            var foos = context.Foos.Where(f => f.FooId == 1).ToList();
        }
```

Make sure you are using the latest of EF.

Comment: I noticed your configurations only map the Key property and not any of the others.  I'm assuming this is because by default EF will try and map property names to column names correct?  Also, your association is only set in Foo Configuration not in Bars. I'm going to try and remove my extra mapping of properties specifically and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: that's right. if properties have the same names as in the db there is no need for mapping. If you define the associations on one entity there is no need to define them on the other.

Comment: Finally got around to trying this out.  You are right, it works, even without the refactoring you did to the model configurations.  I guess I need to investigate my actual mapping a little further and see what is going on there.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just upgraded my project to EF 4.2 without changing any code and it worked.  Wonder if there was something about EF 4.1 that was causing it.  Thanks!